# Как по нажатию кнопки Enter переключать фокус на следующий элемент в Avalonia MVVM

Tags: c#, textbox, avalonia, focus, reactive

У меня есть динамические `TextBox`, они добавляются по нажатию кнопки. Мне необходимо по нажатию кнопки `Enter` внутри `TextBox` переключать фокус на следующий элемент, а если элемента не существует создавать его. Сейчас у меня при создании элемента фокус устанавливается на него.

View:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="40,*">
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="New row" Command="{Binding AddNewRow}" />
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Loaded="Control_OnLoaded"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Аналогия с двумя tb:

````
<Grid RowDefinitions="40,*">
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="New row" Command="{Binding AddNewRow}" />
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Loaded="Control_OnLoaded"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Loaded="Control_OnLoaded"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```
````

View.CS:

```
    private void Control_OnLoaded(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            var tb = sender as TextBox;
            tb.Focus();
    }
```

models:

```
    public class Elements: ViewModelBase
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _text;
    
        public int Id
        {
            get => _id;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _id, value);
        }
    
        public string Text
        {
            get => _text;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _text, value);
        }
    }
```

VM:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddNewRow { get; set; }
        private ObservableCollection<Elements>? _elementsList;
    
        public ObservableCollection<Elements>? ElementsList
        {
            get => _elementsList;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _elementsList, value);
        }
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ElementsList = new ObservableCollection<Elements>(new List<Elements>());
            ElementsList.Add(new ObservableCollection<Elements>
            {
                new()
                {
                    Id = ElementsList.Count + 1, Text = ""
                }
            });
            
            AddNewRow = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
            {
                ElementsList.Add(new ObservableCollection<Elements>
                {
                    new()
                    {
                        Id = ElementsList.Count + 1, Text = ""
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл лучшее решение, в котором для переключения фокуса не используется слой `VM`, и которое работает с двумя `TextBox`-ами.

Для обработки нажатия клавиши `Enter` используем событие `KeyDown`. Плюс помечаем интересующие нас `TextBox`-ы, чтобы при переключении фокуса не переключиться на другие элементы, находящиеся на этой же форме (Используем для этого аттрибут `Tag`):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Loaded="Control_OnLoaded" 
  KeyDown="Control_KeyDown"              
  Tag="First"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text1}" Loaded="Control_OnLoaded"
  KeyDown="Control_KeyDown"
  Tag="Second"/>
```

**Если нужно переключаться змейкой:**

Code-behind будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private void Control_OnLoaded(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    // поскольку разом добавляется два TextBox-а, то фокус нужно поставить на первый из них
    if (tb.Tag == "First")
    {
        tb.Focus();
    }
}

private void Control_KeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (IsLastTextBox(tb))  // если Enter нажат в последнем TextBox-е, то нужно создать новую строку
        {
            CreateNewRow(tb);
        }
        else // иначе фокус должен переключиться на уже существующий TextBox
        {
            SwitchFocusToNextRow(tb);
        }
    }
}

private bool IsLastTextBox(TextBox tb)
{
    var nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(tb, NavigationDirection.Next);
    if (IsOurTextbox(nextElement)) // если tb - последний созданный TextBox, то за ним будет следовать не "наш" элемент
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// "нашим" является TextBox, помеченный либо First, либо Second
private bool IsOurTextbox(IInputElement element)
{
    if (element is TextBox nextTb)
    {
        if (nextTb.Tag == "First" || nextTb.Tag == "Second")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void SwitchFocusToNextRow(TextBox tb)
{
    var nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(tb, NavigationDirection.Next);

    nextElement.Focus();
}

private void CreateNewRow(TextBox? tb)
{
    var dc = DataContext as MainViewModel;
    dc.AddNewRow.Execute(tb.DataContext as Elements).Subscribe();
}
```

**Если нужно переключаться независимо в каждом из столбцов:**

Code-behind будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
TextBox previousFocused;  // предыдущий элемент с фокусом
private void Control_OnLoaded(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    // поскольку разом добавляется два TextBox-а, то фокус нужно поставить не на тот,
    // который был последним, а на тот, которых находится в столбце,
    // в котором был нажат Enter
    if (previousFocused == null || tb.Tag == previousFocused.Tag)
    {
        tb.Focus();
        previousFocused = tb;
    }
    // нужно при переключении фокуса на уже созданный ранее элемент 
    tb.GotFocus += Tb_GotFocus; 
}

private void Tb_GotFocus(object? sender, GotFocusEventArgs e)
{
    previousFocused = sender as TextBox;
}


private void Control_KeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        // если Enter нажат в последнем ряду, то нужно создать новую строку      
        if (InTheLastRow(tb))  
        {
            CreateNewRow(tb);
        }
        else // иначе фокус должен переключиться на уже существующий TextBox
        {
            SwitchFocusToNextRow(tb);
        }
    }
}

private bool InTheLastRow(TextBox tb)
{
    var nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(tb, NavigationDirection.Next);
    // если tb - последний созданный TextBox, то за ним будет следовать не "наш" элемент
    if (IsOurTextbox(nextElement)) 
    {
        // если tb - предпоследний созданный TextBox, 
        // то за ним будет следовать не "наш" элемент
        nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(nextElement, 
                                           NavigationDirection.Next); 
        if (IsOurTextbox(nextElement))
        {
            // если два следующих элемента "наши", то мы не в последней строке
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// "нашим" является TextBox, помеченный либо First, либо Second
private bool IsOurTextbox(IInputElement element)
{
    if (element is TextBox nextTb)
    {
        if (nextTb.Tag == "First" || nextTb.Tag == "Second")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void SwitchFocusToNextRow(TextBox tb)
{
    var nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(tb, NavigationDirection.Next);
    nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(nextElement, NavigationDirection.Next);

    nextElement.Focus();
    previousFocused = nextElement as TextBox;
}

private void CreateNewRow(TextBox? tb)
{
    var dc = DataContext as MainViewModel;
    dc.AddNewRow.Execute(tb.DataContext as Elements).Subscribe();
}
```

Таким образом, теги нам нужны при проверке, что мы не вышли за границы создаваемой таблицы, и для того, чтобы правильно назначить фокус при добавлении новой строки

Comment: К сожалению не работает. Переключение фокуса только по первому столбцу срабатывает. Возможно команда AddNewRow неверна у меня записана, ее нужно какая изначально была, или которую вы писали для первого решения?. А можно ли сделать как первое решение, с использованием VM. У меня в основной программе свойство Tag занято уже) я с помощью него id элемента по нажатию клавиши отслеживаю.
Может есть вариант связаться не в комментариях? Можете мне на почту написать? (Она в профиле указана). Для местного чата у меня репутации не хватает

Comment: Также хотел спросить, для mvvm вообще корректно так много code-behind писать для view? Или это все противоречит паттерну данному?

Comment: Можно ту, которая была изначально. Странно, у меня работает для обоих столбцов. `Id` у вас есть в `DataContext`, его можно оттуда достать, а не через `Tag`. Поскольку этот код управляет только задачами отображения, в данном случае фокусом, ничего страшного нет

Comment: Я еще не преисполнился до того уровня чтобы в codebehind datacontext вызывать) Тогда еще не знал что так можно сделать. Нужно будет позже переделать это.

Comment: Cost, как получается нужно сделать, если использовать первое решение? Мне нужно свойство модели фокус2, но в VM по айди фокус меняется, а айдишник одинаковый.

Comment: @Mikhail, да, там у меня не получилось заставить по нужному столбцу проходить, только по второму. Поэтому и предложил этот вариант. `Id` элемента можно если что получить как `(tb.DataContext as Elements).Id, если это тот же самый идентификатор, что и в `Elements`

Comment: А можете VM скинуть где вы делали по второму способу.  И View полностью. Интересно почему не работает у меня. Можно ссылку на гитхаб

Comment: Вот у меня как то так получилось. https://skr.sh/vNLHOTzIFgg . У вас также? На следующий элемент не переключается. Только по столбцу может перемещаться который выбрал, но на следующий столбец не переходит.

Comment: Мне просто нужно чтобы когда запустил приложение, фокус на первом текстбоксе из двух, затем я нажимаю Enter, и фокус переходит на второй элемент и когда я нажимаю Enter еще раз у меня добавляется новый элемент в коллекцию и фокус попадает опять на первый элемент как и при запуске приложения. Т.е. как бы по порядку чтобы шло как буква Z.

Comment: А, ну я значит неправильно понял. как сделаю, дополню ответ

Comment: Спасибо, жду ответа

Comment: @Mikhail, посмотрите

Comment: Вы гений, огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

**UPD: нашёл более простое решение** https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1557250/248343

**Как заставить добавлять новые `TextBox` по нажатию `Enter`:**
Простейшим способом будет установить кнопке атрибут `IsDefault = true`:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="New row" Command="{Binding AddNewRow}"
        IsDefault="True"/>
```

В этом случае команда будет срабатывать всегда, даже если в фокусе будет не `TextBox`.

Чтобы этого избежать можно добавить к `TextBox` обработчик события нажатия клавиши, например `KeyDown`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"               
         Loaded="Control_OnLoaded" 
         KeyDown="Control_KeyDown"/>
```

axaml.cs:

```
private void Control_KeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {            
        var dc = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
        dc.AddNewRow.Execute();
    }
}
```

**Как менять фокус на следующий элемент, если не надо добавлять новый:**
Вот тут нормального решения не нашёл. Как по мне так не слой `VM` должен заниматься переключением фокуса на `View`. Но как сейчас в Авалонии правильно работать с фокусом не знаю.

А если через `VM`, то

1. В `Elements` добавляем свойство `Focused`
2. Изменяем команду `AddNewRow` так, чтобы она принимала параметр типа `Elements`

```
public ReactiveCommand<Elements, Unit> AddNewRow { get; set; }

...

AddNewRow = ReactiveCommand.Create<Elements>((el) =>
{
    if (el == ElementsList.Last())
    {
        ElementsList.Where(x => x.Focused).Single().Focused = false;
        ElementsList.Add(
            new()
            {
                Id = ElementsList.Count + 1,
                Text = "",
                Focused = true
            }
        );

    }
    else
    {
        ElementsList.Where(x => x.Focused).Single().Focused = false;
        var index = ElementsList.IndexOf(el);
        ElementsList[index + 1].Focused = true;
    }
});
```

3. Подписываемся на событие изменения свойства `Focused`

```
private void Control_OnLoaded(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    var dc = tb.DataContext as Elements;

    dc.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Focused")
        {
            if (dc.Focused)
                tb.Focus();
        }
    };
    tb.Focus(); //установка фокуса для нового элемента
}
```

4. Изменяем вызов команды при нажатии `Enter` в `TextBox`, чтобы передать какой конкретно `TextBox` был нажат

```
private void Control_KeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        var dc = DataContext as MainViewModel;
        dc.AddNewRow.Execute(tb.DataContext as Elements).Subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую это сделать. Вероятно вы правы что не VM должна этим заниматься, скорее всего view-behind

Comment: К сожалению ваше решение не срабатывает, по условию по проверке на последний элемент условие не срабатывает. Даже если я изначально создаю 2 текстовых поля, то фокус по ним не перемещается. Также во View-behind tb.datacontext требует чтобы addnewrow была <object?, Unit>

Comment: Также dc.AddNewRow.Execute(); не срабатывает также как elementslist.last()

Comment: @Mikhail, да, в 4 пункте ошибка была. Исправил вызов команды, посмотрите

Comment: Кажется работает))) Я очень рад, спасибо огромное. А есть источники с информацией какие нибудь, я бы с удовольствием почитал.

Comment: Если вы еще здесь, могли бы подсказать как можно сделать тоже самое только если 2 textbox'a. Сейчас внесу изменения в вопрос. Обозначил как аналогия с двумя tb

Comment: @Mikhail, насчёт двух textbox-ов зависит от того, как они должны изменяться, и что в них будет. Если должен появляться одновременно с первым, то в `Elements` нужно добавить свойство и привязаться к нему. Если абсолютно независимо, то, наверное, вторая коллекция и свой `ItemsControl` для неё. Если они должны появляться змейкой (сначала по горизонтали, а  потом по вертикали), то `WrapPanel` в `ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate`

Comment: они будут создаваться одновременно, текст внутри разный они друг с другом будут связаны только одним свойством. Я создал свойство Text как в первом, но по индексу внутри коллекции уже не переключается.

Comment: @Mikhail, добавил новый ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1557250/248343

Comment: Cost, можешь посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1558315/Как-сделать-импорт-файла-excel-в-свою-коллекцию-avalonia

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии enter вызывается next(1); ну или если находитесь в группе радиокнопки то при нажатии стрелок вверх и вниз .Вероятно недоработано для DatePicker и может еще чего. В работе не тестировано ,но вдруг поможет .

```
private async void next(int napr, int keys = 0)
{
    string? gruname = "";
    IInputElement? a = FocusManager?.GetFocusedElement();
    if (a?.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
    { RadioButton rr = (RadioButton)a; if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rr.GroupName)) { gruname = rr.GroupName; } }
    if (napr == 1)
        await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(a, NavigationDirection.Next));
    else
        await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(a, NavigationDirection.Previous));
    await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a?.Focus());
    if (a?.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
    {
        RadioButton r = (RadioButton)a;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.GroupName) && r.IsChecked == false)
        {
            while (0 == 0)
            {
                if (napr == 1)
                    await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(a, NavigationDirection.Next));
                else
                    await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(a, NavigationDirection.Previous));
                await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a?.Focus());

                if (a?.GetType() != typeof(RadioButton))
                        break;
                RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton)a;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gruname) && gruname != r1.GroupName)
                {
                    if (napr == 1)
                        await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(a, NavigationDirection.Previous));
                    else
                        await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(a, NavigationDirection.Next));
                    await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a?.Focus());
                    return;
                }
                if (keys > 0) { break; };
                if (r1.IsChecked == true && keys == 0) { r = r1; break; }
            }
        }
        r.Focus();
    }
    else if (a?.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)a;
        inputs = 0;
        t.SelectAll();
    }
    else if (a?.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
    {
        CheckBox t = (CheckBox)a;
        t.BorderBrush = Avalonia.Media.Brush.Parse("Black");
        t.BorderThickness = Avalonia.Thickness.Parse("0.5");
    }
}
```